# DateTime Serialization Returning incorrect Minutes SYMFONY 3

Tags: php, json, datetime, serialization, symfony

i have a problem (Sorry for my Bad English Again)

So i created an API with Symfony 3 on JSON  , it is working , but the DateTime data's are not returned correctly .

i mean , only the hours are returned correctly but the minutes aren't

This is my Entity , Horaire.php

```
<?php

namespace CBMedBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\VirtualProperty;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type;

/**
* Horaire
*
* @ORM\Table(name="horaire")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CBMedBundle\Repository\HoraireRepository")
* 
* @ExclusionPolicy("all")
*/
class Horaire
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var time
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Debut", type="time", length=10)
 * @Type("DateTime<'h-m-s'>")
  * @Expose
 */
private $debut;

/**
 * @var time
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="EntreeSalle", type="time", length=10)
 * @Type("DateTime<'h-m-s'>")
  * @Expose
 */
private $entreeSalle;

/**
 * @var time
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="HeureAnesthesie", type="time", length=10)
 * @Type("DateTime<'h-m-s'>")
  * @Expose
 */
private $heureAnesthesie;

/**
 * @var time
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Operation", type="time", length=10)
 * @Type("DateTime<'h-m-s'>")
  * @Expose
 */
private $operation;

/**
 * @var time
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="incision", type="time", length=10)
 * @Type("DateTime<'h-m-s'>")
  * @Expose
 */
private $incision;

/**
 * @var time
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="finOpe", type="time", length=10)
 * @Type("DateTime<'h-m-s'>")
  * @Expose
 */
private $finOpe;

/**
 * @var time
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Reveil", type="time", length=10)
 * @Type("DateTime<'h-m-s'>")
  * @Expose
 */
private $reveil;

/**
 * @var time
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Sortie", type="time", length=10)
 * @Type("DateTime<'h-m-s'>")
  * @Expose
 */
private $sortie;

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CBMedBundle\Entity\Interventions", cascade=   {"persist"})
* @Expose
*/
private $Interventions;
//
etc....
```

As you see , i used the `JMS\Serializer\Annotation\`

And i indicated That the DateTime type is in this format `@Type("DateTime<'h-m-s'>")`

And this is what i get when i test my API with POSTMAN
[image: IMAGE API POSTMAN]

My Real datas on phpmyAdmin
[image: phpmyAdmin Datas]

i have "01" on every minutes

How do i fix this please ?

Comment: Isn't the format <'h-m-s'> supposed to be hour-minute-seconds??? Where do you set day-month-year, can't understand the french...

Comment: oh indeed sorry , it's minutes , not month

Comment: i edited my post , but it still have the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this annotation instead:

```
@Type("DateTime<'H:i:s'>")
```

See what that shows please. This is based on PHP DateTime format.

Comment: Thanks , it works ! Nice to see you again Sir Alvin Bunk !